# rollback on JTA Transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, glassfish

Suppose I have a managed bean and I have defined an `EntityManager`. I was wondering how transactions work and how they behave in a variety of different situations. From the documentation I understood that `flush()` is actually used to overwrite the delay on the commit and do it immediatelly. So in the example bellow I was expecting `demo` to persist in the DB and `demo2` not to. But it seems like it is all seen as a single transaction (from my understanding). Why is this happening? Why no further annotation or hibernate methods of `begin()` and `commit()` are needed to define the beginning and the end of the transaction? I feel like I am confusing different things here...

```
@Stateless
public class Testing {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "testDB")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void doSomeWork(){
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        em.persist(demo);
        em.flush();
        //some code that makes it crash
        Demo demo2 = new Demo();
        em.persist(demo2);
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [Container managed transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html) all session beans are by default run within transaction. That means, if some exception occurs that causes transaction to rollback the changes to `demo` are rolled back as well.

Here is some useful information about how `flush()` works: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting#Flush

Comment: How is "within transaction" specified? Do I have a single transaction for each method call? What if there are 2 calls irrelevant to each other one after the other and the second one fails. Will the first be rolledback too?

Comment: It depends how you specify it - by default each method has `Required` transaction attribute, which means if there is a transaction already present it is used an if it is not present it is created. You can however change this by using `javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute` annotation - for example so that each time a new transaction is created, or no transaction should be used at all.

Comment: I wanted to have a new transaction for every individual method call (calls from outside the bean). I have been through the documentation you linked but I am not really familiar with it. Will the default configuration be sufficient?

Comment: If you want to be sure that every method is called within new transaction annotate your method with `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)`, wherease `REQUIRES_NEW` is a constant within `javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType` (this you'll need to import statically)

Comment: Alright thanks. Concerning the link you sent me, I am not sure how that agrees with what I am actually seeing on my code. It specifies that if you `persist`, the database is not going to be written until you either `flush` or `commit`. In my code, even if I do not call any of these methods, I can see the data written in the DB. Why is that?

Comment: The transaction will be automatically committed when the method execution finishes successfully. In fact, in container managed transactions you cannot call `commit()` manually.

Comment: I see. So calling `flush()` just after `em.persist(demo2);` just like in my example is useless? Cause I remember seeing it in an example

Comment: If you want to achieve that data are persisted directly into database then yes. `flush()` is usually implemented differently for various providers. The most common usage of flush is when you want to make sure that data you've just altered are available for other queries. But I would avoid using `flush()` in container managed transactions.